# How can I pass updated views result to drupalSettings?

Tags: views, 8, javascript

I've created a custom views style plugin.

I'm trying to pass the views results into a drupalSettings. I'm able to access the dataset like below using the template_preprocess:

```
$variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['test']['dataset'] = $items;
```

However, the results isn't updating with views exposed filter. Though, if I set a drupalSettings based on views results count. It does update. So, I tried to turn off the views caching, but still no luck.

Here's my current code:

```
function template_preprocess_test(&$variables) {
  $items = &$variables['test']['items'];

  $variables['content']['list'] = [
    '#theme' => 'test_dataset_list',
    '#items' => $items
  ];

  $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['test']['dataset'] = $items;
}
```

Here's how I set the dataset from the custom views style:

```
function template_preprocess_test_views_style(array &$variables) {
  // Only run the preprocessor if it is a view.
  if (empty($variables['view'])) {
    return;
  }

  $view = $variables['view'];
  $style = $view->style_plugin;
  $options = $style->options;
  $items = [];

  foreach ($variables['rows'] as $k => $row) {
    // @todo should use render arrays instead of actual output
    $item['dataset'] = [];
    $item['dataset']['custom1'] = (isset($row['#custom1']) && !empty($row['#custom1'])) ? $row['#custom1'] : NULL;;
    $item['dataset']['row'] = $row;
    $items[] = $item;
  }

  $content = [
    '#theme' => 'test',
    '#test' => [
      'items' => $items
    ],
  ];

  $variables['content'] = $content;
}
```

Comment: Which hook runs first?

Comment: @NoSssweat template_preprocess_test_views_style, then the variables are being passed to template_preprocess_test.